# How to get gmail notification when new email arrives?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail-api

I have created a java web application that authenticates the gmail user using OAuth API. Currently I have to check for any new email at regular interval. Now I want to get notification from gmail when a new email arrives. Doing this it will save my calling gmail API at regular interval. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: From the results of my search, it is not possible to do so. Google only supports this for mobiles. The closet thing to your requirement is Gmail desktop notifications, but that is a totally different thing.

Answer (score 0):

try using [**Atom**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed) feed; it's a XML feed provided by gmail containing all new emails in the inbox